# PHP: function mysqli_connect_errno () VS function mysqli_connect_error ()?

Tags: php

Tengo una duda entre estos dos, entiendo que el errno me va a tirar un string, lo leí en la docu que viene embebida en el IDE, sobre el connect_error dice:

> - Adjusts the result pointer to an arbitrary row in the result

No me queda claro a qué se refiere con que ajusta el resultado a una celda arbitraria.

Gracias!

Comment: Bienvenida, ayudaría mucho por favor si agregas tu código saludos

Comment: No es necesario. No tengo problemas con el código, sólo quiero saber en la teoría lo que hace.

Comment: Seria bueno que editaras tu pregunta e indicaras cual es el `IDE`. Quizás una captura de pantalla también serviria para demostrar lo que mencionas.

Comment: No tengo ningún error! La documentación la toma el IDE de la página de php cuando se hace control click en la función para ver de qué se trata, al igual que cualquier IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te diría que tu `IDE` esta mostrando información errónea, ya que el mensaje que citas corresponde al método:

#### [`mysqli_data_seek`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.data-seek.php)

> Ajustar el puntero de resultado a una fila arbitraria del resultado.
>   [...]Devuelve TRUE en caso de éxito o FALSE en caso de error.

Y con respecto los métodos en cuestión:

#### [`mysqli_connect_error`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.connect-error.php)

> Devuelve **una cadena con la descripción del último error de conexión**.
>   [...]Una cadena que describe el error. Devuelve `NULL` si no ha ocurrido ningún error.

#### [`mysqli_connect_errno`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.connect-errno.php)

> Devuelve **el código de error de la última llamada**
>   [...]Un código de error para la ultima llamada a `mysqli_connect()`, si ha fallado. cero significa que no ha ocurrido ningún error.

Comment: Estan uno debajo del otro en la docu, debo haber leído mal. Listo gracias!